# Define custom atrributes in attr module

Tags: python, python-attrs

I'm looking for way, that I can define class attributes as I want.

For example, I tried this way:

```py
@attrs.define
class MyClass:
    pass


MyClass(a=1, b=2)
```

But recieving the TypeError:

```
TypeError: MyClass.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

Is it possible to implement what i want?

Comment: by 'as you want' you mean after initializing the class ?

Comment: I can't set attribute, if that attribute is not exists in class vars.I want to define attributes regardless of the specified fields in class

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, v)


o = MyClass(a=1, b=2)

print(o.a, o.b)
```

Which results in:

```
1 2
```

Comment: Yep, but I need to display the class as `MyClass(a=1, b=2)` format

Comment: @Чёткаяворона define `__repr__`  method in your class than.

Answer (score 0):

You **must** tell attrs about the attributes that you want to use, otherwise it can't write an efficient `__init__` (and other helper methods like `__repr__`) for you. It's both data and documentation.